# Creating additional tables to support custom Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 abstract models:

```
class AdditionalModel(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    y = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now I have my models.py:

```
 class MainModel(BaseModel):
    z = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

On migration, I need to create two tables, one for **MainModel** which extends the BaseModel and another for "**mainmodel_additional_model**" which gets additionally created for MainModel.

I was trying to achieve this using save() method. Not quite getting there, also what are the standard ways to do this.

Comment: abstract model is not created in database. If you want to create table for both, you should use one-to-one relationship instead of inheritance.

Comment: Abstract model is being inherited by MainModel, so one table will be created for it. All I want is to have another table dynamically created with MainModel prefix.